# Simple fan with single bone / weight paint doesn't appear correctly while posing

Tags: weight-painting

So I'm trying to create a simple fan like object that folds up from right to left.  You can see my single bone along with how I painted the weights below:

[image]

And here is the result when I go into pose mode and rotate the bone 90 degrees.  I would expect left side vertices to be influenced less so that the entire object can fold into itself.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a vertex that is controlled by only one bone, even if the weight of this bone on this vertex is 0.01, the influence will be 100%.

Example: I have this square, the bone has a weight of 0, 0.01 and 1 on its 4 vertices:

[image]

If I move the bone, the vertices with a weight of 0.01 will move as much as the vertex that has 1, the vertex that has a weight of 0 won't move:

[image]

So if you want to vary the weight of a bone on a vertex, you necessarily need a second bone. If I create a second bone that has a weight of 0.01 on the vertex that has already a weight of 0.01 from the first bone, this second bone will share a 50% influence on this vertex.

For your object, you could create a series of bones, for example 5 bones, parent the object to the armature *With Automatic Weights*, then give your bones number 4, 3 and 2 a *Copy Rotation* constraint with bone 5 as *Target*, and a decreasing influence of 0.75, 0.5 and 0.25:

[image]

Here is what it gives:

[image]

Comment: oops sorry Robin, I hope I didn't delete your edit  ;)